# How to parse a JSON with an unknown property path?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I've got some JSON strings and I need to parse with Python 3.5. Here is an example of the JSON string:

```
"termsAndCourses":{  
  "Semester 2016":{  
     "000001":{  
        "courseId":"000001",
        "title":"Python",
     },
     "000035":{  
        "courseId":"000035",
        "title":"Java",
     },
     "000051":{  
        "courseId":"000051",
        "title":"C#",
     }
}
```

I need to use Python 3.5 to get each course's title, **but the property path may be changed and unknown, which means I cannot do it in this way:**

```
result = json.loads(json_str)
print(result["termsAndCourses"]["Semester 2016"]["000001"].title)
```

In this example above, the two sections of property path **"Semester 2016"** and **"000001"** are completely different and irregular from each of the JSON string.

Then how should I get the content from **"title" property?**

Comment: `[c['title'] for c in result["termsAndCourses"]["Semester 2016"].values()]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to iterate into your JSON object with a for loop?

```
for semester in result["termsAndCourses"]:
    for course in semester:
        print course
```

(Not sure about the exact syntax)

Answer (score 1):

this `result = json.loads(json_str)` produce python dictionary consist `items` each item `key` and `value`  so to access any value use `d[key]` in your case nested dictionaries so :

```
>>> rr["termsAndCourses"]["Semester 2016"]["000001"]['title']
u'Python'
```